# PL/SQL Trigger Fetch data from the table to update the same table

Tags: oracle, plsql

I plan to use trigger to auto-update the bloodquantitystock in table blood_stock whenever any blood is registered in table blood. In order to update bloodquantitystock, I need to fetch the previous bloodquantitystock from table blood_stock and +1 it. Do you guys perhaps any idea how to solve this? Thank you in advance.
[This is my blood_stock table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58uE0.png)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_stock
AFTER INSERT ON blood
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE  
v_bloodstock blood_stock.bloodquantitystock%TYPE := 1; 
BEGIN 
v_bloodstock = (SELECT SUM(blood_stock.bloodquantitystock) FROM BLOOD WHERE bloodbankid = blood.bloodbankid); 
UPDATE blood_stock 
SET bloodquantitystock = v_bloodstock 
WHERE bloodbankid = (SELECT bloodbankid FROM blood WHERE bloodid=(SELECT max(bloodid) 
FROM blood) AND bloodtype = SELECT bloodtype FROM blood WHERE bloodid=(SELECT max(bloodid) FROM blood)); 
END;
```

Comment: trigger does not make sense.  it is being called for each row updated, so you need to reference :OLD, :NEW bind variables. You can't update records that the trigger is on, that will cause a "mutating trigger" error.  You can workaround that with a compound trigger, but I think you need to re-evaluate what you have.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the table `blood` has one row for incoming (and outgoing?) blood (say 5 doses of type A for bank BB001 on 2022-01-21), and the table `blood_stock` has the sums (e.g. 500 doses of type A in bank BB01)? If so, what do you need the latter table for? Isn't all the information needed in the `blood` table already? Just add up the data ad hoc and you are fine, I'd say.

Comment: Instead of using another table to maintain `BLOODQUANTITYSTOCK`, it may make more sense to use a VIEW just doing a SUM and grouping by whatever columns you want. A MATERIALIZED VIEW with FAST REFRESH would be ideal if the structure of your data supports it.